# Нет переносов текста в label на winphone. Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin

При использовании длинного текста в метках, текст не переносится и выводится одной строкой. На android такого нет.

Пробовал различные опции: `lineBreakMode`, `Horizontal` и `VerticalOptions` - не помогает. Ручной перенос строк не подходит, прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно использовать FillandExpand в HorizontalOptions. Растягивать следует по вертикали.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае может помочь только реализовать перенос с помощью LabelRenderer.
Примеры тут. https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs

например

public CustomLabel : label { 
}

```
public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var txt = new TextBlock {MaxLines = 3};
        SetNativeControl(txt);
    }
}
```